# Repository pattern with manual queries

Tags: c#, mysql, repository-pattern

First of all I'm using manual queries.

I'm having some issues organizing my service and repository layer. The problem is that I have some objects that are rather large aggregate objects that need to have basic data from their constituent objects in display mode but when being processed it needs to have all its child objects fully developed to avoid null errors and some other business logic errors.

So for example a Job has Customer, Supplier, Site, Machine, User, Run, Store, Component, Document, CheckSheet, Requisitions, OrderItems.

When displaying a Job we want to have things like customer name, supplier name, user, component description, store name, machine number, site name, number of checksheets. As you can see it's mostly just descriptions. However when I want to process a Job I need all of those objects fully developed.

Currently the way I'm doing it, which I don't like, is that when fetching a Job from the JobRepository it fully develops the Job object directly and fills the rest of the child objects with display values only and when I want to process a job I go ahead and call the respective repositories for each object to get a full object. There are some problems with this approach.

If we add a field to an object I have to potential look for changes in more than 1 places, which kind of defeats the purpose of a repository.
I can only have 2 'modes' of retrieval which is fully developed or display only. What if I want some of the child objects to be more developed but not others? For example when displaying OrderItems I'd like to have the Part object within it fully developed with prices and all.

I feel like things will get out of control soon with duplication everywhere and I need a better long term solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean "loaded" when you say "developed"? i.e. loaded into memory, read from the db?

Comment: Yes loaded into memory. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Your question feels really vague. There are probably 1000 solutions to your (very unspecific) problems, but it sounds a bit as if you are trying to write (parts of) a database framework yourself, instead of just using one (e.g. ado.net). Bind your object to the datasource and you don't have to care (much) about synchronization, data load and storage, because it is done for you. You "just" have to implement the business logic in your object. So before you redevelop a framework without knowing about it, you should give it a try (or at least look at some db components and get inspired).